# Determine the closest point

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, coordinates

Math dummy question:

Say I have a "root" coordinate (x0,y0) and a list of other coordinates ((x1,y2),(x2,y2),...(xn,yn))
Is there a computationally better method to find the nearest point to (x0,y0) than to scan through and get all the distances to (x0,y0) using the Pythagorean theorem?

Thank you

Comment: `math.dist()`..

Comment: If it's a one-off, not really (you can avoid the square roots as MrSmith42 notes), but if you're doing this many times with different (x0,y0) and same(-ish) (x1,y1),...,(xn,yn), then you have options.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I'm actually putting it into a loop, (x1,y1),...,(xn,yn) always change. What do you suggest?

Comment: Where does the list of points come from?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat From a group of moving objects. Like, humans for example.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than doing 2 multipltication?

I don't think so.

---

Just be aware that **you do not need to compute the square root** to compare which point is closer (because sqrt is a monotonoic incleasing function).

So compute (x0-xi)^2+(y0-yi)^2 for each i in {1,..,n}
and take the one with the smallest value. That's the nearest point.